# embedded widget that relies of jquery, what if main page has jquery already loaded?

Tags: jquery

If I create a widget, where someon just links to:

```
www.example.com/my.js
```

which places a small widget on their website, and my widget relies on jquery, how can first check if is loaded already on the page?

**what if 1.3.1 is loaded and I require 1.4.2?**

Comment: You could load the correct jQuery from your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall there is a function in jQuery "$().jquery" that returns the version. Or "jQuery.fn.jquery;"

To check for jQuery entirely do something like

if(typeof(jQuery) != "undefined")
{
   Bla bla code
}